# Responsive CSS many screens but it overlap

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I want to build with 3 screen. Pc size display iphone and ipad but it's like sometimes iphone use ipad feature or PC display use ipad feature.

I use mediascreen min-width821 max821 and max391.I write 3 different codes for those 3 screen. I want those codes to run in their right screens.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that you have provided same value to both Desktop and Tablet i.e. 821px.

Use this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 391px) {
    /* Code here for Mobile */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
    /* Code here for Tablet */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 821px) {
    /* Code here for Desktop */
}
```

Comment: This is only a wild guess on your part since he didn't provide any markup. Questions without provided markup are considered off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]